# How to keep Tupperwear unstained?

Tags: storage-method, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to remove stains (e.g. from curries and pasta sauces) from plastic containers?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/is-there-any-way-to-remove-stains-e-g-from-curries-and-pasta-sauces-from-plast)

I find that when storing curries or tomato based sauces in the freezer they stain the tupperwear and also leave a lasting smell. Is there a tupperwear that avoids this and how do I best clean tupperwear to get rid of the colour and smell?